# How to pass resolved dependencies in state manager view controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

I am trying to access the response from dependencies in the controller. [[ui-router]](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

```
$stateProvider.state('project', {
 url: '/:projectId/:forkId',
 resolve: {
 foo: function() {
  return {
    bar: "4143"
  };
  }
 },
 views: {
'main': {
  templateUrl: 'partials/analysis/project/main.html',
  controller: 'mainCtrl'
},
sidebar: {
  templateUrl: 'partials/analysis/project/sidebar.html',
  controller: 'sidebarCtrl'
}
}
});
```

My mainCtrl is defined in some other angular module.

Issue: How to access the foo function's returned object in controller?

```
p = angular.module('project', []);

p.controller('mainCtrl', ['foo', function(foo) {}]);
```

PS. Code is written in coffeescript.

Comment: Are you not able to access `foo.bar`

Comment: Nope.Its looking for foo service and it is not able to find it.

Comment: If you create the content in js more people can help you :)

Comment: Seems like you are passing a function to `resolve` definition, whereas it take an object map. Not sure because i don't understand coffeescript much.

Comment: I changed the code to javascript. Please look at this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve.

Comment: I am not sure, but can you try to inject the module which contains the state definition into the `project` module and try.

Comment: @Chandermani he tagged it Coffeescript, maybe you should understand Coffeescript if you're going to be participating in Coffeescript questions

Comment: Can you check to see if `ngscope($0).$state.current.resolve` has anything in `$state.current.resolve`? You'll need to Inspect an element in the controllers scope (and the $0 may only work in Chrome).

Comment: Sorry, ngscope is `angular.element(selector).scope()` (I forgot to clarify that)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should add `controller: 'mainCtrl'` to the `project1` state, and make sure they(controller and the stateProvider config) are in the same module? (the latter is probably unnecessary, didn't test.)

A complete example from Ionic:
http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/data-the-right-way/